# How to obtain codesigned application certificate info for ios app

Tags: ios, certificate, ipa

We have an application for ios  Finally - we did our codesigning, but i would like to add an extra security check - within the executable itself.

I know apple had signed the app.How to get apple signed info in my app? Such as apple public key or something else?

Comment: I'm assuming this is for piracy detection? Or do you have strict security expectations that your iOS app needs to meet? You should know that iOS is a very dynamic platform, and there's little you can do to ensure such a high level of security without having your own code running at the kernel level monitoring syscalls and doing instrumentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to make assumptions about Apple's Fairplay DRM, assuming you intend to validate it, there is no way for you to do this without having Apple's keys, but there are other indicators for tampering/piracy that I assume you are looking for.

There are several ways to check if your app has been tampered with. Let's assume that Apple's Fairplay DRM is secure, then if you detect your app running unencrypted, its very likely it was tampered with, and more likely that it was pirated. You can check for the `cryptid` bit in the `LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO` segment (more on this [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Crack_prevention)). But keep in mind that piracy tools are a lot more sophisticated nowadays, and many will patch the `cryptid` value at runtime. You could probably use the `dyld_*` APIs to check for loaded libraries, and if the `cryptid` hacker is loaded your app is probably compromised. They can of course change the name of the library, and you're back to square one. They can always change the value of the `cryptid` bit on disk while the app is running, and switch it back when the app terminates.

So while you have several avenues to explore, in actuality, there's nothing you can do. Apple has tried to prevent jailbreaking via technical and legal measures, but they have failed. And as long as you can jailbreak, you can tamper with binaries in these ways.

Comment: yeah I want to check wheater my app has been tampered with by certificate info.when my app lunching,I can check the certifiacte info and display a reminder to the user ;

Comment: by certificate i think you really just mean make sure its signed and encrypted, in which case the cryptid check will work. But as I said, even this is no guarantee that no other code is running inside your process, because of things like dynamic code interposition via `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`. This is one of those things probably best left alone, unless you want to engage in a cat and mouse game with pirates.

Comment: As I know,my code been signed with my private key before submitting to apple store and apple encrypted  the app with the userinfo when user download it.I just want to protect the app that download from other app store .

Comment: In android app,I can get my public-key when the app has been signed . in the mac os ,also get the certificate info by the code or command such as codesign -dvvv **app